# Setting a string array in a struct to us in function

Tags: c++

using the latest version of code blocks I'm trying to add an array of synonyms to a verb. I have a struct as follows

```
struct word
{
    std::string word;
    std::string synonyms[];
    int code;
};
```

and set later with

```
inline void set_verbs(word *vbs)
{
    vbs[INVENTORY].code = INVENTORY;
    vbs[INVENTORY].word = "INV";
    vbs[INVENTORY].synonyms = {"I", "ITEMS", "INVENTORY"};
}
```

(in a different include file). It was working perfectly with just .code and .word but I can't figure out how to make this work with a string array or a string vector

Have done a lot of googling around but can't find anything like what I'm trying to do, can anyone help? Thanks a mil :)

Comment: You cannot do an array like that. Use `std::vector` instead (`std::vector<std::string> synonyms;` ... `vbs[INVENTORY].synonyms.push_back("I");` etc.)

Comment: @crashmstr consider posting that as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: Thanks a million, that's solved my problem very neatly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For collections of an unknown size, use `std::vector`. Use `push_back` to then add items to you vector.

```
struct word
{
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> synonyms;
    int code;
};

inline void set_verbs(word *vbs)
{
    vbs[INVENTORY].code = INVENTORY;
    vbs[INVENTORY].word = "INV";
    vbs[INVENTORY].synonyms.push_back("I");
    vbs[INVENTORY].synonyms.push_back("ITEMS");
    vbs[INVENTORY].synonyms.push_back("INVENTORY");
}
```